# How to bridge the unbridgable on Windows 7?

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge

I have a small Windows box I once used as a means of making a 4G LTE network (USB modem) available on a wider network, basically bridging its connection to a standard "Local Connection" on 100Base-T. The machine was running XP.

XP would not allow me to bridge the connections using the usual simple means of selecting both and right-clicking to select "Bridge Connections". For some reason the 4G connection was considered ineligible to participate. So I looked for and found a simple registry hack that permitted the XP box to act as a bridge.

A few years pass, the XP box is long retired, but the need arises again. I have a Win 7 box that can act in this role, but the same restriction applies when I try to use the inbuilt "Bridge Connections", and I can no longer locate any documentation on what the XP fix was.

So, tl;dr -- how can I set up a bridge in Win7 by going under the skin? Or is there another (native) solution?

Comment: This is a question for superuser.

Comment: OK, could a kind mod please migrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is being disallowed at the driver level because the 4G/LTE connection is listed as a Modem, which is assumed to be a low-speed connection unsuitable for bridging. The device manufacturer (driver writer) makes this decision. If there's a way to override this (and I swear at one time I did it), the information doesn't seem to be on the internet.

The two possible workarounds are to use ICS or to enable IP routing, both of which are going to be slower than a true bridge. Enabling the box to act as a router involves a registry change (HKLM/CCS/Services/Tcpip/EnableIpRouting = 1) and adding an appropriate route.

ICS is the simplest, but it too acts at the TCP/IP layer so it adds overhead. But it does work, and for this relatively slow connection is probably good enough.

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting to do tethering.  Providers used to charge extra for this but I just looked online and it appears that [they might no longer have this locked down](http://www.cnet.com/news/what-verizons-fcc-tethering-settlement-means-to-you-faq/).  So, you should be able to do it.

I imagine you would need to setup basic routing on the Win7 box along with DHCP server for the wired LAN advertising itself as the default route.  PAT should be setup as well.

Comment: Thanks, but no, this isn't tethering. I'm using a 4G data modem licensed and contracted for exactly this use. But my motives have no bearing on the technical part of this question -- I'm looking for a way to bridge connections, regardless of the type, that Win7 considers to be ineligible for their simplified process. I did it once, but can't find the info any more.